# jQuery $.get() is not executed on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit

When a form is submitted, I want to asynchronously invoke an email-sending script `order.php` with some `$_GET` parameters.

The jQuery `$.get()` function doesn't execute and there are no errors displayed in console.

HTML markup:

```
<form name="submit" id="orderconfirm" action="somefile.php">
<input type="hidden" name="orderkey" id="orderkey" value="somekey"/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="orderemail"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#orderconfirm').submit(function() {
   var key = $('#orderkey').val();
   var email = $('#orderemail').val();
   var url = 'order.php?key=' + key + '&mail=' + email;
   $.get(url);
});

});
```

It's really strange because a similar script (also `$.get()` with a simple URL) works just fine. I'm also sure that the `order.php` script works fine and the path is correct. The problem is that somehow `$.get(url)` is not executed and no request is sent.

The submit handler works fine too - for example an alert worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: `.submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: the problem happens with the default behavior from browser on form submission. you need to prevent the default from being executed. optionally you can even change the type of button from 'submit' and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prevent default browser action by using `preventDefault()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#orderconfirm').submit(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var key = $('#orderkey').val();
       var email = $('#orderemail').val();
       var url = 'order.php?key=' + key + '&mail=' + email;
       $.get(url);
    });    
});
```

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Also you can use `return false;` to restrict the form submission

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#orderconfirm').submit(function(event) {
       var key = $('#orderkey').val();
       var email = $('#orderemail').val();
       var url = 'order.php?key=' + key + '&mail=' + email;
       $.get(url);
       return false;
    });    
});
```

To submit the form after `$.get` try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#orderconfirm').submit(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var key = $('#orderkey').val();
       var email = $('#orderemail').val();
       var url = 'order.php?key=' + key + '&mail=' + email;
       $.get(url,function(){$('#orderconfirm').submit()});
    });    
});
```

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: you may also have to manually submit the form after `$.get` if you want to submit the form also

Comment: How do I submit the form manually? Because $.get works fine now but the form is not submitted

Comment: Using preventDefault() fixed the $.get() problem but it stopped the form from submitting. How do I make the form submit after $.get() was executed?

Comment: Try this `$.get(url,function(){$('#orderconfirm').submit()});`

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't prevent default browser behavior. Add `event.preventDefault` method:

```
$('#orderconfirm').submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var key = $('#orderkey').val();
   var email = $('#orderemail').val();
   var url = 'order.php?key=' + key + '&mail=' + email;
   $.get(url);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#orderconfirm').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

})
```

and use valid `$.get`

```
$.get( "order.php", {'key':key,'mail': email});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `return false` or [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault) like,

```
$('#orderconfirm').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var key = $('#orderkey').val();
   var email = $('#orderemail').val();
   var url = 'order.php?key=' + key + '&mail=' + email;
   $.get(url);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#orderconfirm').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var key = $('#orderkey').val();
   var email = $('#orderemail').val();
   var url = 'order.php?key=' + key + '&mail=' + email;
   $.get(url);
});

});
```

the problem happens with the default behavour from browser on form submission. you need to prevent the default from being executed. 
optionally you can even change the type of button from 'submit' and try.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to fix this.

**1**.Use [`e.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent browser's default behavior from submitting the form.

```
    $('#orderconfirm').submit(function(e) { // 'e' here is new
       var key = $('#orderkey').val();
       var email = $('#orderemail').val();
       var url = 'order.php?key=' + key + '&mail=' + email;
       $.get(url);
       e.preventDefault(); // and this line is new
    });
```

**2**. Or just change the `submit` type to `button`.

```
    <input type="button" value="submit"/>
```

By the way, you can get values as parameters instead of string. [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
$('#orderconfirm').submit(function(e) {
   var key = $('#orderkey').val();
   var email = $('#orderemail').val();
   var page = 'order.php';
   $.get(page, {mail: email, key: key}); // this line
   e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.get( "order.php", { key: key , mail: email } );
```